# Android app works on stock android but gives NPE on touchwiz and avd

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running android 4.1.2 touchwiz + 4.2.2 cm10.1 in dual boot. Now, the problem is that my app works perfectly on cm10.1 but crashes and gives NPE on touchwiz rom as well as on any AVD I run. Its a long code so I don't want to put up everything. Here is the logcat and the line of code where its gives this exception. Thanks for the help.

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

static final LatLng abcd = new LatLng(xx, xx);
String addresss;
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2,
            container, false);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();


   **NPE here** 
    Marker abcd = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(abcd)); 

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(abcd, 15));

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

logcat:-

```
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.example.mapsapiv2demo.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:49)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 09:18:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please excuse the horrible format in which i posted this. Seem to be having a hard time to even get the logcat show properly. Hope you can excuse this for once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that's something to do with `SupportMapFragment.getMap()`, from API docs (emphasis is mine):

> public final GoogleMap getMap ()
>
> Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this fragment.
>
> Returns
> the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. **This can also happen if Google Play services is not available.** If Google Play services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

Google Play services may not be available on Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2 TouchWiz.